# Get route params in CanActivate method Angular 2

Tags: angular

I am currently using `LazyLoading` to load the module but I am not able to access the router params when I reload the page.

The router params is empty when I reload, but I can access within the component but not the `Guard`.

**Code**

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): any {
   debugger;
   console.log(route.params); // empty when reloading
   this.router.events.subscribe((event) => {
      if (event instanceof ActivationStart) {
          console.log(event);
      }
   });
}
```

The above code does not log any `console events` because the `routing does not happen`

How can I access the route params within `CanActivate` when I reload the page? Is there any hack so that I can access them?

Comment: have you tried using `router.params.subscribe`?

Comment: @PardeepJain: Subscribe is not possible here because route.params is not an observable stream.

Comment: @PardeepJain since routing is not started yet the events will not emit.

Comment: @baj9032 this event does get subscribed, but I am not receiving any param `this.actRoute.params.subscribe`

Comment: Can you post your url before reload the page?

Comment: `http://localhost:4200/component/2` path in routing `component/:id`